# How to install the autocomplete plugin when using gm

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, greasemonkey

I'm trying to autocomplete some text-fields with

```
$('#username').replaceWith('<input id=\"username\" type=\"text\" name=\"user_name\">');


$("input#username").autocomplete({
    source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
});
```

I know there's a jQuery autocomplete plugin. How do I include the plugin?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autocomplete plugin is [obsolete/deprecated](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/).  It's now part of [the jQuery-UI plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).
Also, jQuery-UI has been tested to work with GM, I haven't heard that anyone's done the same for autocomplete.

Add jQuery-UI by making sure that these 2 lines are in your metadata block:

```
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.3/jquery-ui.min.js
```

You may have to uninstall then reinstall the script to get the libraries copied over.

Answer (score 0):

your script is correct. you only need to include jquery as explained **[here](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Third-Party_Libraries#jQuery)**

Comment: Does it mean that the library contains all jQuery plugins? I used // @require        http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js to include the jquery library. When loading the code above firebug says:$("input#username").autocomplete is not a function. Wouldn't it mean that the plugin isn't included?

Comment: Well, that's not the matter :(. Also used the .noConflict() function.

Comment: I un- and installed the script again to see whether I missed sth. Same error.

Comment: are you including autocomplete plugin? if not, include plugin too from http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jq-autocomplete

Comment: Well, that was my question. How do I include it?